# Error occurred when using chrome.runtime.connect and postMessage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, postmessage, message-passing

## What I try to do

A Chrome extension can quick search evernote. It's quite like vimium but for evernote searching. When The 'e/E' key pressed, an omnibar show. Then I can input some query strings, suggestions will be fetched asynchronized. Press ESC to hide it.
[This is my extension](https://github.com/blurm/evernote_quick_search)

Append the omnibar(iframe) when web page loaded, then using chrome message passing to communicate between iframe and the background.js to call the searching function

At the beginning it works fine, but when I opened several chrome windows, and after a few hours, then perform the search again, error occurred.

## Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'impl' of undefined
    at getPrivateImpl (extensions::utils:121:30)
    at Port.publicClassPrototype.(anonymous function) [as postMessage] (extensions::utils:139:20)
    at EomnibarIn.onInput (chrome-extension://khjineoieblnbagekihfblbfkkapcbda/js/eomnibarIn.js:76:29)
    at HTMLInputElement.input.on (chrome-extension://khjineoieblnbagekihfblbfkkapcbda/js/eomnibarIn.js:60:49)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (chrome-extension://khjineoieblnbagekihfblbfkkapcbda/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3:10316)
    at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (chrome-extension://khjineoieblnbagekihfblbfkkapcbda/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3:8343)
```

## Code

#### js code embeded in iframe page

```js
class EomnibarIn {
    constructor() {
        this.backgroundPort = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'eomnibarPort'});
        this.backgroundPort.onMessage.addListener((msg) => {
                console.log(msg);
                this._displaySuggestions(msg.queryString, msg.suggestions);
        });
    }

    onInput(event) {
        // Get queryString and other staff

        this.backgroundPort.postMessage({
            action: 'performSearch',
            queryString: queryString,
            maxSuggestion: this.maxSuggestion
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var barIn = new EomnibarIn();
});
```

#### background page

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    if (port.name == 'eomnibarPort') {
        port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg.action === 'performSearch') {
                const suggestions = eomnibarController.performSearch(
                    msg.queryString, msg.maxSuggestion);
                port.postMessage({queryString: msg.queryString, suggestions: suggestions});
            }
        });
    }
});
```

## My Question

Which part goes wrong? I don't have any clue how to debug this since it doesn't happen every time.

Comment: Chrome is known to create and destroy hidden prerendered tabs for omnibox searches so I think you should check if the web page is loaded in a tab with `tab.index == -1`. I have no idea what your extension actually does based on your description in the question so either post a link to the full extension code or... good luck :)

Comment: @wOxxOm I thought no one might have the patience to go through the codes. But yes, you're right. I add the link in my question. You can give it a try on Chrome. It's quite handy for Evernote users who use Linux. Basically, it's quite like vimium but only for Evernote searching.

Comment: @wOxxOm  I also tried as you said, using `chrome.tabs.getSelected` to check tab id in iframe js, just regular number not `-1`.

Comment: Not `id`, but `index`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Sorry, my bad. The index is 0. The omnibar is just a regular iframe attached in current page. I don't quite get what it does with tabs.

Comment: My guess was that your content script runs in a prerendered hidden tab which exists only for a fraction of a second and when your content script tries to communicate it fails at the moment the hidden tab is destroyed. Try simply wrapping the messaging code in try/catch.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't think it's content script's fault. Code which send messages to background page is loaded by <script> in iframe html page, not loaded by content script.

Comment: Well, don't nitpick, I didn't study the extension. However my idea is still worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message definitely means the port has been disconnected. There are a few reasons this might happen. A common one is that the extension reloaded/updated/reinstalled. If you hit the reload button from chrome://extensions, all old ports disconnect. Another possible cause is that something anomalous happened (e.g. your laptop's battery ran low and entered low-power mode).

The fix is a little bit complicated... You have to detect the port's disconnection (using port.onDisconnect form the content script) and establish a new connection. Unfortunately, it's not as simple as calling chrome.runtime.connect() again. If your extension was updated to a new version, you lose access to the old extension context and its chrome.* APIs. You have to reload a whole new iframe (and remove the old iframe).

I do this in my extension [Saka Key](http://github.com/lusakasa/saka-key). You can check its source code.

By the way, iframes that contain extension pages aren't content scripts. They actually are privileged contexts with direct access to the background page.

Comment: It looks like the extension reloaded issue. I will do further test. I installed Saka Key, very well designed, nice job:)

Comment: Another related question, what do you use for the page and iframe communication? I use MessageChannel and the port disconnected problem also happened from time to time. Do you have any idea what will be the possible causes?

Comment: I use my own library [mosi](https://github.com/eejdoowad/mosi) which is built on regular extension messaging. Now that I think about it, Saka Key doesn't really use iframes. My other extension [Saka](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saka/nbdfpcokndmapcollfpjdpjlabnibjdi) does, but it's not open source. I've never used MessageChannels, so I have no idea.